# How to use pykalman filter_update for online regression

Tags: recursion, filtering, regression, kalman-filter

I want to use Kalman regression recursively on an incoming stream of price data using kf.filter_update() but I can't make it work. Here's the example code framing the problem:

The dataset (i.e. the stream):

```
DateTime             CAT      DOG
2015-01-02 09:01:00, 1471.24, 9868.76
2015-01-02 09:02:00, 1471.75, 9877.75
2015-01-02 09:03:00, 1471.81, 9867.70
2015-01-02 09:04:00, 1471.59, 9849.03
2015-01-02 09:05:00, 1471.45, 9840.15
2015-01-02 09:06:00, 1471.16, 9852.71
2015-01-02 09:07:00, 1471.30, 9860.24
2015-01-02 09:08:00, 1471.39, 9862.94
```

The data is read into a Pandas dataframe and the following code simulates the stream by iterating over the df:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

history = {}
history["spread"] = []
history["state_means"] = []
history["state_covs"] = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx == 0: # Initialize the Kalman filter
        delta = 1e-9
        trans_cov = delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(2)
        obs_mat = np.vstack([df.iloc[0].CAT, np.ones(df.iloc[0].CAT.shape)]).T[:, np.newaxis]
        kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=2,
                          initial_state_mean=np.zeros(2),
                          initial_state_covariance=np.ones((2, 2)),
                          transition_matrices=np.eye(2),
                          observation_matrices=obs_mat,
                          observation_covariance=1.0,
                          transition_covariance=trans_cov)

        state_means, state_covs = kf.filter(np.asarray(df.iloc[0].DOG))
        history["state_means"], history["state_covs"] = state_means, state_covs
        slope=state_means[:, 0]
        print "SLOPE", slope

    else:
        state_means, state_covs = kf.filter_update(history["state_means"][-1], history["state_covs"][-1], observation = np.asarray(df.iloc[idx].DOG))
        history["state_means"].append(state_means)
        history["state_covs"].append(state_covs)
        slope=state_means[:, 0]
        print "SLOPE", slope
```

The Kalman filter initializes properly and I get the first regression coefficient, but the subsequent updates throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
SLOPE [ 6.70319125]
  File "C:/Users/.../KalmanUpdate_example.py", line 50, in <module>
KalmanOnline(df)
  File "C:/Users/.../KalmanUpdate_example.py", line 43, in KalmanOnline
state_means, state_covs = kf.filter_update(history["state_means"][-1], history["state_covs"][-1], observation = np.asarray(df.iloc[idx].DOG))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pykalman\standard.py", line 1253, in filter_update
2, "observation_matrix"
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pykalman\standard.py", line 38, in _arg_or_default
+ '  You must specify it manually.') % (name,)
ValueError: observation_matrix is not constant for all time.  You must specify it manually.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems intuitively clear that the observation matrix is required (it's provided in the initial step, but not in the updating steps), but I cannot figure out how to set it up properly. Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pykalman allows you to declare the observation matrix in two ways:

- [n_timesteps, n_dim_obs, n_dim_obs] - once for the whole estimation
- [n_dim_obs, n_dim_obs] - separately for each estimation step

In your code you used the first option (that's why "observation_matrix is not constant for all time"). But then you used filter_update in the loop and Pykalman could not understand what to use as the observation matrix in each iteration.

I would declare the observation matrix as a 2-element array:

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

n = df.shape[0]
n_dim_state = 2;

history_state_means = np.zeros((n, n_dim_state))
history_state_covs = np.zeros((n, n_dim_state, n_dim_state))

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx == 0: # Initialize the Kalman filter
        delta = 1e-9
        trans_cov = delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(2)

        obs_mat = [df.iloc[0].CAT, 1]

        kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=2,
                          initial_state_mean=np.zeros(2),
                          initial_state_covariance=np.ones((2, 2)),
                          transition_matrices=np.eye(2),
                          observation_matrices=obs_mat,
                          observation_covariance=1.0,
                          transition_covariance=trans_cov)

        history_state_means[0], history_state_covs[0] = kf.filter(np.asarray(df.iloc[0].DOG))
        slope=history_state_means[0, 0]
        print "SLOPE", slope

    else:
        obs_mat = np.asarray([[df.iloc[idx].CAT, 1]])

        history_state_means[idx], history_state_covs[idx] = kf.filter_update(history_state_means[idx-1], 
                                                            history_state_covs[idx-1], 
                                                            observation = df.iloc[idx].DOG, 
                                                            observation_matrix=obs_mat)
        slope=history_state_means[idx, 0]
        print "SLOPE", slope

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history_state_means[:, 0], label="Slope")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It results in the following output:

```
SLOPE 6.70322464199
SLOPE 6.70512037269
SLOPE 6.70337808649
SLOPE 6.69956406785
SLOPE 6.6961767953
SLOPE 6.69558438828
SLOPE 6.69581682668
SLOPE 6.69617670459
```

[image: pykalman kalman filter online estimation of the regression parameters]

The Pykalman is not really good documented and there are mistakes on the official page. That's why I recomend to test the result using the offline estimation in one step. In this case the observation matrix has to be declared as you did it in your code.

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

delta = 1e-9
trans_cov = delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(2)
obs_mat = np.vstack([df.iloc[:].CAT, np.ones(df.iloc[:].CAT.shape)]).T[:, np.newaxis]

kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=2,
                  initial_state_mean=np.zeros(2),
                  initial_state_covariance=np.ones((2, 2)),
                  transition_matrices=np.eye(2),
                  observation_matrices=obs_mat,
                  observation_covariance=1.0,
                  transition_covariance=trans_cov)

state_means, state_covs = kf.filter(df.iloc[:].DOG)

print "SLOPE", state_means[:, 0]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(state_means[:, 0], label="Slope")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Anton, thanks a lot for the elaborate answer and taking your time to actually amend the code. Now it works as expected.